# get req.body from node express server side code to take array from front end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to save a user's array to mongo and it goes from the bridge to the posts.  The posts receive it as some weird object with string versions of its indices.  I'm trying to convert it to a normal array so it can save to mongo but it's very sensitive and keeps erroring out, is there some sort of parsing operation I'm missing?

**bridge:**

```
static saveUsers(users){
    try{
        let command = 'saveUsers';
        return axios.post(url + command, {
            params: users
        });
    } catch(err){
        reject(err);
    }
}
```

**posts:**

```
router.post('/saveUsers', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = await loadCollection('users');
    let userArray = req.body.params.toArray(); // this causes error
    await collection.insertMany(
        userArray
    );
        res.status(201).send();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static saveUsers(users){
    try{
        let command = 'saveUsers';
        return axios.post(url + command, {
            params: JSON.stringify(users) // send users as a string with stringify
        });
    } catch(err){
        reject(err);
    }
}
```

```
router.post('/saveUsers', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = await loadCollection('users');
    let userArray = JSON.parse(req.body.params) // parse params
    await collection.insertMany(
        userArray
    );
        res.status(201).send();
});
```